# How to create bubble tree binary chart using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, tree

I'm trying to create bubble tree chart, didn't find any solution in d3, added snap [image]

Comment: It isn't clear why you couldn't use a D3 tree with a  [radial](https://observablehq.com/@d3/radial-tidy-tree) layout, which can generate a chart like your image with tweaking to show donut charts for some nodes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.